# HTML code not woring in IE?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, safari, href

I am trying to apply a jump to section\ function in my HTML code using the following code:

```
<a href="#BACK_TO_TOP"><input id="To_Top_Button" title="Terug naar zoek Database"></a>
```

which references back to the section marked as follows

```
<a id="BACK_TO_TOP"><img src="../Images/Banner.png" alt=" Header" width="1500" height="152"></a>
```

This works fine with Chrome and Safari but fails in IE strange because the following works in IE:

```
<Strong><i><li type="square"><a href="#C5">Diploma’s</a></li></i></Strong>
```

which links to the following

```
        <STRONG><font face="Century Gothic" size="2" color="#DC143C">
        <li type="square"><a id="C1">Productontwikkeling...</a></li>
    </font></STRONG>
```

the reference used to implement this code is found at

```
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_locations
```

Comment: Why have you got an `input` element inside the `a` tag?

Comment: There are *many* things wrong with this code. If it works at all in any browser, it's down to luck. Please validate it.

Answer (score 2):

You *cannot* nest interactive elements in HTML. Both `<a>` and `<input>` are interactive.

Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org) (that is not your only error, although it is the cause of this problem).

If you want a link that *looks* like a button, then start with a link and then use the standard tool for describing how things should look: CSS.